COM Port not opening when running as .EXE using Pyinstaller
I have a Python application that opens a serial connection to a COM port. This COM port is a USB connected to some external hardware. When I run the application from the terminal, it works as expected.
However, when I build the application into an EXE using Pyinstaller and run it, it gives me the following error:
File "serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM15': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
The strange thing is that if I print out the serial = Serial() instance I get:
Serial<id=0x1c27e79dfc0, open=True>(port='COM15', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=5, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
which seems to suggest the port is open (open=True)? Why then does it immediately throw this exception?
I tried switching COM ports, restarting the computer, running as Administrator... nothing seems to work.
